# Clevertap Events Data in Python

Tags: python, clevertap

I am using https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-server-api-examples to get clevertap events data in python but I am getting error
 HTTP Error 405: HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

```
from python.api_v0.clevertap import CleverTap
clevertap = CleverTap('xxx-xxx-xxxx','xxx-xxx-xxxx')
query = {
    "event_name": "c_city_selected",
    "from": 20180610,
    "to": 20180611
}
res = clevertap.events(query)
```

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/CleverTap/clevertap-csv-download solved my problem. Just add the parameters as shown.